# How to use tflearn deep learning for document classification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, tflearn

I am using tflearn and tensorflow to classify documents. However I am facing issue with the size of the document and training time, the length of my largest document is ~98000 words and using this for the building the network is going to be extremely time consuming. I was looking at different methods to reduce the dimensions of the data or some technique that will be fast enough to train the model. I saw doc2vec and word2vec and built the respective models but am not sure of how to use them with tflearn. I am also classifying the documents by creating doc2vec and word2vec model and getting the feature vector by averaging the feature vectors of all words that exist in the model vocabulary in the doc. Can I use this final feature vector for DNN or does someone have other suggestions that I can use.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily build Document Classification models with TensorFlow and integrated into it TF.Learn library.

There are even examples of the various document classifications models in examples folder: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/learn#text-classification

The fastest model for any length document will be Bag of Words model - one that averages embeddings of words. This is recommended baseline for any document classification problems too. Then you can try more complicated models like RNNs or CNNs.

Here is example code for it:

```
def bag_of_words_model(features, target):
  """A bag-of-words model. Note it disregards the word order in the text."""
  target = tf.one_hot(target, 15, 1, 0)
  features = tf.contrib.layers.bow_encoder(
      features, vocab_size=n_words, embed_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE)
  logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features, 15, activation_fn=None)
  loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(target, logits)
  train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
      loss,
      tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
      optimizer='Adam',
      learning_rate=0.01)
  return ({
    'class': tf.argmax(logits, 1),
    'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    }, loss, train_op)
```

For more details how to run it, see here - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py

You can easily extend more fully connected layers (e.g. DNN part) by adding `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected` before `logits` are computed.

You can also initialize embeddings from pre-trained checkpoint with word2vec or other embeddings by using `tf.contrib.framework.init_from_checkpoint`([see documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.framework/checkpoint_utilities)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to deep learning and tflearn I was using this example [link]https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/bidirectional_lstm.py and wanted to change the 1st layer of the network and use a deep network classifier, any suggestions on how to achieve that maybe? The Max_document_length is the main issue and want some kind of dimensional reduction is nothing else

Comment: the first layer in the model you pointed - is embeddings. the classification can be switched in the last layer `net = regression(`. Note, `tflearn` is different from TensorFlow's own libraries. But in this case same thing applies -  to change to DNN you just need to add more `fully_connected` layers.

Comment: I did figure it out earlier, about softmax and classification. What I want to know is if there is a way to reduce the number of features with doc2vec or word2vec or some other technique before passing it to the embedding layer